# Is the x-ray girl lying?

Tags: probability

The x-ray girl [Natasha Demkina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natasha_Demkina) claims to be able to see through people.

She had to prove her ability in a test where she had to match six specified anatomical anomalies to seven volunteer subjects. She was able to match three out of the six specified anatomical anomalies correct, and she found the person that didn't had any anatomical anomalies.

I would like to know the probability that Natasha would guess at most 4 persons correct if she would assign the anatomical anomalies randomly.

I would model it like that: The 7 people can be seen as a perturbation of 7 numbers $$\pi = ( \pi_1,\dots,\pi_7).$$

Lets denote with $A$ the set of perturbations of length 7 that are distinct  from $\pi$ in at most 4 entries. Then, the probability of event $A$ would be given by $$\frac{|A|}{7!}.$$

My approach is that $$ |A| = \binom{7}{0} \cdot 1+ \binom{7}{1}\cdot 0 + \binom{7}{2} \cdot a_5+\binom{7}{3} \cdot a_4+\binom{7}{4} \cdot a_3$$
holds where $a_i$ denotes the number of perturbations of length $i$ where each entry has to be different for some arbitrary but fixed perturbation of length $i$.

My question is: Is this approach correct and is there a possibility to calculate $a_i$? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you want the probability that the test result is at least as *good* as actually observed, i.e. the probability for $4$ or *more* matches (under the zero hypothesis of equidistributed random permutations). The (differently defined) $A$ would thus be

$$|A| = {7\choose 7}\cdot !0+{7\choose 6}\cdot !1 +{7\choose 5}\cdot !2+{7\choose 4}\cdot !3$$
where $!n$ counts the [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). Some recursion and other methods to compute derangements are given in the referenced Wkipedia article. The first few values are of course easily computed as $!0=1$, $!1=0$, $!2=1$, $!3=2$, so tat $|A|=92$ and the probability of merely *guessing* correctly four or more out of seven is $\approx 0.018$. Of course we should rather compare with someone making *educated* guesses than random guesses, but that's harder to model ...

Comment: I guess the x-ray girl has some powers then. Thank you!

Comment: It depends on how scientific the experiments are made. Instead of actual X ray we should of course rather think of an extraordinarily good ability of observations (the "Dr. House" way). And in medicine, the proof is in the healing.